Connect external device as a keyboard to fresh instance of Windows 11
I've bought a PC and I'm in the process of configuring it. The issue I have is that I have only wireless keyboard and mouse, thus I can't connect them to my new PC, because I don't have any controller to do so. Do you have any ideas how I could do that? I was thinking about making my phone to act as a keyboard without any success.
The equipment I have is as follow:
Logitech Master M3 mouse
Logitech Master MX keys keyboard (both without usb receiver)
Windows 11 Laptop
Android phone
The host I want to connect to is on Windows 11.

Your going to need at least a keyboard or mouse with wire or wireless with receiver.

I was afraid that's my only option unfortunately

Without the receiver you're out of luck. I believe these have the option to connect using Bluetooth, but Bluetooth likely only works inside an already-installed OS with the correct drivers installed.
You will need to either have the Logitech USB receiver, or find an alternative keyboard and mouse that are either wired or include a required receiver.
You don't have other options.
